# CSS absolute position clipping image

Tags: css, css-position

I have an absolute positioned image inside a relative container.  I would like to use negative margin but it is clipping my image.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div id="container" class="clearfix">
  <div class="left-col">
     /*CONTENT*/
  </div><!-- /.left-col -->
    <div id="my-image"><img src="images.png" height="596" width="392" alt=""></div><!-- /#image -->
</div><!-- /#container -->
```

Here is my CSS:

```
#container{
position: relative;
background-color: orange;
    width:600px;
    height:600px;
}

#my-image{
background-color: blue;
position: absolute;
z-index: 1150;
bottom:0;
right:-130px;
width:398px;
height:596px;
}
```

Here are the results:

[image]

Negative bottom works, but negative right and left do not.  I have simplified the code and put generic names for stuff.

Thank for your input!

Comment: Do you have `overflow: hidden` in there anywhere? A jsFiddle of link would make this easier to help with.

Comment: What is the `z-index` of the element hiding the image (the brownish looking element)?. `#container` doesn't have a `z-index` set. So if the the brownish looking element has a positive `z-index` set, it would be hiding any element inside `#container`, regardless of the images `z-index`, as the image resides inside `#container`.

Comment: is that all HTML? you should create a JSfiddle that reproduces your problem

Comment: Thanks everyone for your input, I had a power failure at my office and my server went down.  I got it back up and realized that I had overflow:auto on my sticky footer css.  Much appreciated!!

Comment: *"I would like to use negative margin but it is clipping my image."* - negative margin for which element..? I don't see any margin in that code...